# Access bootstrap variables without importing it in every file in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, asset-pipeline, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to use the boot-strap variables and mixins in my css files. Below is the CSS file which needs them.

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/dashboard/_common.css.scss
// import the CSS framework
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap-custom";

// make all images responsive by default
img {
  @extend .img-responsive;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

// override for the 'Home' navigation link
nav.navbar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: $body-bg;
}
.....
```

Below is the piece of code in app/assets/stylesheets/dashboard.css.scss:

```
 *= require _bootstrap-custom
 *= require_tree ./dashboard
 *= require_self
```

This is the corresponding directory structure..
[image]

`_bootstrap-custom.scss` already imports all the variables, and mixins etc.

```
@import "bootstrap-variables-custom";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
....
```

Inside the dashboard folder, I've to explicitly import the `bootstrap-custom` and the `bootstrap-variables-custom` wherever I need to use them, although it is already imported in the `dashboard.css.scss` using the require directive:
`*= require _bootstrap-custom`

On removing these imports from the common.css file, I get the following error: `Undefined variable: "$body-bg".`

Although, I've gone through the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825485/rails-3-access-to-twitter-bootstrap-variables-mixins-without-importing-it), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: That is pure sass, but this question is in context of asset pipeline of ruby-on-rails, and the sprockets gem.